# File "bot.py", line 6 if message.text == "Hello": ^ IndentationError: unexpected unindent ** Process exited - Return Code: 1 **

Tags: python

```py
from telebot import types
import telebot; bot = telebot.TeleBot('')
bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text', 'document', 'audio'])
if message.text == "Hello":
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "How are you")
elif message.text == "/help":
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Send Hello")
else:
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "I dont andestend. Right /help.")
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

```
File "bot.py", line 6
    if message.text == "Hello":
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected unindent
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 3 строка начинается с @.
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text', 'document', 'audio'])
if message.text == "Hello":
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "How are you")
elif message.text == "/help":
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Send Hello")
else:
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "I dont andestend. Right /help.")
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

У тебя здесь несколько ошибок

```py
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text', 'document', 'audio'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == "Hello":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "How are you")
    elif message.text == "/help":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Send Hello")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "I dont undestend. Right /help.")
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Даю объяснение:

- У тебя на строке 3 и 5 стоят два декоратора. Судя по тому, что этот обработчик делает, тебе нужны только текстовые сообщения. Если тебе нужны и документы с аудио, напиши в комментариях и я поправлю
- Где у тебя стоят `if-elif-else`, отсутствует 4 пробела - а в Python это важно, иначе он будет считать, что это к функции не относятся
  Лучше пойми, а не копируй и вставляй. Это поможет тебе быть программистом получше

И ещё, ты выложил токен своего бота, что **никогда нельзя делать!**. Я изменю твой вопрос и уберу его

Comment: Мне нужны и текст и аудио и документы и видео даже будет хорошо

Comment: @P1tin изменил ответ